# Sideloading app with ngrok not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, ngrok, microsoft-teams

Repro steps...

1. I created a Teams tab app via the [teams yeoman generator](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-teams) (installed via npm).
2. I followed the [locally hosted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/debugging#locally-hosted) option that uses ngrok.
3. I started ngrok with `./ngrok http 3007 --host-header=localhost:3007` (still running) and copy/pasted the generated urls into my `manifest.json`
4. I started another terminal session and ran `gulp serve`
5. I created my package via `gulp manifest`
6. I tried to sideload the generated zip and get the error messages: `Error while reading manifest.json: Failed to find icon "https://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io/assets/tab-44.png" file in the package Failed to find icon "https://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io/assets/tab-88.png" file in the package`
    (subdomain redacted)

This is what I've confirmed/debugged...

1. Going to `https://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io/assets/tab-44.png` and `https://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io/assets/tab-88.png` works fine in the browser. I see the default smiley face icon and see the request in the ngrok terminal and web interfaces.
2. I don't see any requests coming from Teams attempting to fetch the icons in the ngrok interfaces.
3. I've also tested that I can reach the icons from my phone.
4. I've unzipped the generated package and it only contains the `manifest.json` with the correct ngrok urls.
5. My tenant has enabled sideloading of apps.
6. I am an owner of the Team I'm trying to sideload this app into.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *outline* and *colour* are relative file paths to PNG icons. Please put both the icons (tab-44.png & tab-88.png) as part of package along with *manifest.json* file.

Comment: You're correct. Here's the schema reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/schema